# Conditional waits in AWS Step Functions that monitor database readiness, S3 events and glue jobs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step function that looks currently like this:

```
{
  "Comment": "RDS Step Functions",
  "StartAt": "CopyLatestSnapshot",
  "States": {
    "CopyLatestSnapshot": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "${aws_lambda_function.snapshot-copy.arn}", 
      "Next": "WaitTenMinutes"
    },
    "WaitTenMinutes": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 600,
      "Next": "ExportSnapshotToS3"
    },
    "ExportSnapshotToS3": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "${aws_lambda_function.snapshot-export.arn}", 
      "Next": "WaitFiftyMinutes"
    },
```

I would like to alter this so instead of `WaitXXXMinutes` steps I have an event-driven approach, so the "wait steps" listen for some kind of event and go forward (or fail upon timeout) when an actual event happens in the system.

I have the following event examples currently:

- database snapshot taken and appears in S3
- database is restored from a snapshot
- database engine upgraded (so DB is offline and online again),
- snapshot deleted from s3
- glue job finished.

Even if I cover some of these with conditional waits that would be fine.

Note that I can not use Lambda for these waits as Lambda timeout is max 15 minutes and some operations take longer time.

Answer (score 0):

To initiate the workflow, you could configure a Cloudwatch Events rule which triggers the state machine. Following steps can leverage Codebuild projects for validating the respective states, bounded by a timeout configuration